# My cursor is blinking and the style of everything is cycling

Tags: cursor

When I boot into Ubuntu, the cursor blinks and the style of everything cycles through three different things. For example, fonts on all the dialogue boxes change, the colors of the tile bars change, etc. It gives me a warning for some kind of system error, but it won't tell me anything about it, and submitting it can't do much given that my internet also doesn't seem to be working.

I have tried rebooting, and even using earlier versions of Ubuntu. It doesn't help. Also, there doesn't seem to be any way to turn off the computer through the menus. If I click the icon in the corner and select shut down, it asks me whether I want to lock or log off. If I log off, there's a button to shutdown, which brings up a box asking if I want to shutdown with no buttons.

Comment: Is your Mouse Scroll Wheel Stuck?  Is your Trackpad Broken?

Comment: They both work fine when I boot into Windows.

Comment: Can you press Ctrl + Alt + F3 to get to a terminal?

Comment: I can open a terminal fine. The only problems I noticed that aren't purely cosmetic are the lack of internet and the lack of a way to shutdown besides doing a hard reset.

Comment: Try `sudo service network-manager stop` and `sudo service gdm stop` from a terminal and then `sudo service network-manager start` and `sudo service gdm start` and post your results.

Comment: The results in order were: "network-manager stop/waiting", "gdm: unrecognized service", "network-manager start/running, process 11103", and "gdm: unrecognized service".

Comment: Do you know your Window Manager?

Comment: No, I don't know my Window Manager.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

seemed to fix it, but I had to restart again to get the internet running.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and here is what worked for me: in Screen Display settings select 'Unknown Display' and deactivate it. After applying the changes everything should work fine.